# How to remove Thunderbird badges on Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome shell dock

Tags: gnome, 17.10, thunderbird, dock

Specifically, I want to remove the "unread messages" indicator to the top right of the thunderbird icon on the dock in stock Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME shell. For instance, I have an orange circle with a "9" inside in white, to indicate the number of unread messages. In general I don't want any badges, but specifically right now I would like to get rid of the one on the thunderbird icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off "Show in the messaging menu" in Thunderbird prefs.

[image]